# Why there are still duplicated elements after I converted Array to HashSet

Tags: java

I have a simple Array:

```
String[] names = {"apple","apple","orange","orange"};
System.out.println("length is "+ names.length); //length is 4
```

I try to have a collection without those duplicated elements in the array, since Java doc says `Set` is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, so I use `Set` to remove the duplicated elements:

```
Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
System.out.println("length is "+ nameSet.size()); //length is 4 still
```

But the `nameSet` still contains duplicated elements, why my Set doesn't have unique elements?

And how to solve my problem without iterate through the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 9):

You must be running different code

```
String[] names = {"apple","apple","orange","orange"};
System.out.println("length is "+ names.length); //length is 4

Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
System.out.println("length is "+ nameSet.size()); //length is 2
```

prints as expected.

```
length is 4
length is 2
```

Comment: If you replace the <String> with your custom object class, you will see the same result as mine

Comment: Override `.Equals` and `.HashCode` for your own classes..

Comment: @Mellon If you're using a custom class you've written posting an example using `String` is useless. There's a huge difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks, I will make a new post for my question.

Comment: No, you should not. Your problem will be solved by overriding the two methods as stated above, surely the internet is filled with examples of that.

Comment: Jeroen, before you saying that, please check my new post (you will know why I am not able to do what you suggested) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381722/remove-duplicated-elements-in-array-by-using-set-in-my-case