# Remove duplicated elements in array by using Set in my case

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jakarta-ee, set

I have a `Array` of object, since I am using a 3rd party library, the array is got by calling one method from the library, **I am not able to access the** `MyObject` **class**.

```
//I have no access to MyObject class, I am sure the objects contain duplicated elements.
MyObject[] objects = SOME_LIB_CLASS.getObjects(); 
System.out.println("length is "+ objects.length); //length is 6
```

I try to remove duplicated elements in objects, I use `Set`:

```
Set<MyObject>  objectSet = new HashSet<MyObject>(Arrays.asList(objects));
System.out.println("length is "+ objectSet.size()); //length is 6 still
```

But the `objectSet` still contains duplicated elements, why & how to solve my problem without iterate through the array?

Comment: An alternative: create a wrapper class for the object type you receive and implement the `Equals` and `Hashcode` methods there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the set still contains "duplicate" elements than the equals method of your objects does not what you expect it to do.

Duplicates in a `HashSet` are determined by the `equals` implementation.

If you can not change the implementation of `MyObject.equals()`( because you don't have the source code - it is a library class), I recommend to use a `TreeSet` and provide a special comparator.

For example

```
public class Main {

    public static class MyObject {

        public int value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObject [value=" + value + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException {
        Set<MyObject> myObjects = new TreeSet<MyObject>(
                new Comparator<MyObject>() {

                    public int compare(MyObject object1, MyObject object2) {
                        return object1.value - object2.value;
                    }
                });

        addMyObjects(myObjects);
        addMyObjects(myObjects); // try to add the duplicates

        System.out.println(myObjects);
    }

    private static void addMyObjects(Set<MyObject> set){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
            myObject.value = i;
            set.add(myObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It contains duplicated entries, because `MyObject` doesn't overwrite `equals` and `hashcode`. If you can't access the class, then you have to iterate over the array, and check for differences manually.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to print hashcode of the objects, I think those objects are not same but have same values for there fields.
and if MyObject is your class, override equals and hascode method to make set working.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code help you

```
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            al.add("hello");
            al.add("hi");
            al.add("hello");
            al.add("dadsa");
            al.add("hello");

            // add elements to al, including duplicates
            HashSet hs = new HashSet();
            hs.addAll(al);
            al.clear();
            al.addAll(hs);

            for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.i("element ", al.get(i).toString());

            }
```

It will remove all duplicate values from arraylist